# Read deadlock when using pipes to execute multiple shell commands on the same process

Tags: c++, linux, shell, pipe

**I am making a C++ program that needs to run multiple commands in the same bash shell instance.** I need this because some of the commands are setting a bash variable that needs to be read by a subsequent command.

I am using [pipes](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) to make file descriptors that are then read and written to using [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write), the other ends of these pipes are connected to a child that is made using [fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

**A problem arises when a command doesn't return an output, such as setting a bash variable.** In the following code, the read will hang forever on command number 2. I've been searching around for a couple days and there doesn't seem to be a way to detect when the command has finished running without closing the pipe somewhere. I believe that if I close the pipe, I won't be able to reopen it, and that would mean I'd need to make a new bash shell that doesn't have the variables loaded.

Additionally, I can't be sure which commands won't return an output as this code will get the commands it needs to run from a web server and would like to avoid concatenating  commands with '&&' for granular error reporting.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inPipeFD[2];
    int outPipeFD[2];

    // Create a read and write pipe for communication with the child process
    pipe(inPipeFD);
    pipe(outPipeFD);

    // Set the read pipe to be blocking
    fcntl(inPipeFD[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(inPipeFD[0], F_GETFL) & ~O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(inPipeFD[1], F_SETFL, fcntl(inPipeFD[1], F_GETFL) & ~O_NONBLOCK);

    // Create a child to run the job commands in
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) // Child
    {
        // Close STDIN and replace it with outPipeFD read end
        dup2(outPipeFD[0], STDIN_FILENO);

        // Close STDOUT and replace it with inPipe read end
        dup2(inPipeFD[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        system("/bin/bash");
    }
    else // Parent
    {
        // Close the read end of the write pipe
        close(outPipeFD[0]);

        // Close the write end of the read pipe
        close(inPipeFD[1]);
    }

    // Command 1
    char buf[256];
    string command = "echo test\n";
    write(outPipeFD[1], command.c_str(), command.length());
    read(inPipeFD[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    cout << buf << endl;

    // Command 2
    char buf2[256];
    command = "var=worked\n";
    write(outPipeFD[1], command.c_str(), command.length());
    read(inPipeFD[0], buf2, sizeof(buf2));
    cout << buf2 << endl;

    // Command 3
    char buf3[256];
    command = "echo $var\n";
    write(outPipeFD[1], command.c_str(), command.length());
    read(inPipeFD[0], buf3, sizeof(buf3));
    cout << buf3 << endl;
}
```

**Is there a way to detect that a child's command has finished without having to close the pipe?**

Comment: Does this all have to be done manually (fork/exec etc.)?  If not I'd recommend [`boost.process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io) and make use of the async IO functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to set `bash` in interactive mode by starting it with `system("/bin/bash -i");` and to set the prompt to the exit code of the last command.

First, a convenience function to make writing and reading simpler:

```
std::string command(int write_fd, int read_fd, std::string cmd) {
    write(write_fd, cmd.c_str(), cmd.size());
    cmd.resize(1024); // turn cmd into a buffer
    auto len = read(read_fd, cmd.data(), cmd.size());
    if(len == -1) len = 0;
    cmd.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(len));
    return cmd;
}
```

Then in your parent process:

```
    sleep(1); // ugly way to make reasonably sure the child has started bash
    int& out = outPipeFD[1]; // for convenience
    int& in = inPipeFD[0];   // for convenience

    // first, set the prompt
    std::cout << command(out, in, "export PS1='$?\\n'\n") << '\n';

    // then all these will print something
    std::cout << command(out, in, "echo test\n") << '\n';
    std::cout << command(out, in, "var=worked\n") << '\n';
    std::cout << command(out, in, "echo $var\n") << '\n';
```

This way you will always have something to read - and you can also use it to verify that the command executed correctly.

---

If your `bash` requires a real terminal in `-i`(nteractive) mode, we have to do it without it. The idea:

- Add `echo $?` + a delimiter to every command sent
- Set the pipes in non-blocking mode to be able to catch misc. bad situations, like if the command `exit` is sent.
- Read until the delimiter is found or an error occurs.

To make the delimiter something hard to guess (to not be able to easily force reading to get out of sync) I would generate a new delimiter for every command.

Here is an example of what it could look like with those ideas in place with inline comments:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// a function to generate a random string to use as a delimiter
std::string generate_delimiter() {
    thread_local std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution dist('a', 'z');
    thread_local auto gen = [&]() { return dist(prng); };

    std::string delimiter(128, 0);
    std::generate(delimiter.begin(), delimiter.end(), gen);

    return delimiter;
}

// custom exit codes for the command function
enum exit_status_t {
    ES_WRITE_FAILED = 256,
    ES_READ_FAILED,
    ES_EXIT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
};

// a function executing a command and returning the output and exit code
std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, exit_status_t> command(int write_fd,
                                                           int read_fd,
                                                           std::string cmd) {
    constexpr size_t BufSize = 1024;

    // a string that is unlikely to show up in the output:
    const std::string delim = generate_delimiter() + "\n";

    cmd += "\necho -e $?\"\\n\"" + delim; // add echoing of status code
    auto len = write(write_fd, cmd.c_str(), cmd.size()); // send the commands
    if(len <= 0) return {{}, ES_WRITE_FAILED};           // couldn't write, return

    cmd.resize(0); // use cmd to collect all read data
    std::string buffer(BufSize, 0);

    // a loop to extract all data until the delimiter is found
    fd_set read_set{};
    FD_SET(read_fd, &read_set);
    while(true) {
        // wait until something happens on the pipe
        select(read_fd + 1, &read_set, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        if((len = read(read_fd, buffer.data(), buffer.size())) <= 0) {
            // Failed reading - pipe probably closed on the other side.
            // Add a custom exit code and the delimiter and break out.
            cmd += "\n" + std::to_string(ES_READ_FAILED) + "\n" + delim;
            break;
        }

        // append what was read to cmd
        cmd.append(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + len);

        // break out of the loop if we got the delimiter
        if(cmd.size() >= delim.size() &&
           cmd.substr(cmd.size() - delim.size()) == delim)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cmd.resize(cmd.size() - delim.size()); // remove the delimiter

    // put what was read in an istringstream for parsing
    std::istringstream is(cmd);

    // extract line by line
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    while(std::getline(is, cmd)) {
        output.push_back(cmd);
    }

    // extract the exit code at the last line
    exit_status_t retval = ES_EXIT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    if(not output.empty()) { // should never be empty but ...
        retval = static_cast<exit_status_t>(std::stoi(output.back(), nullptr));
        output.resize(output.size() - 1);
    }

    return {output, retval}; // return the pair
}
```

Test driver:

```
int main() {
    int inPipeFD[2];
    int outPipeFD[2];

    // Create a read and write pipe for communication with the child process
    pipe(inPipeFD);
    pipe(outPipeFD);

    // Set the read pipe to be non-blocking
    fcntl(inPipeFD[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(inPipeFD[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(inPipeFD[1], F_SETFL, fcntl(inPipeFD[1], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    // Create a child to run the job commands in
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) // Child
    {
        // Close STDIN and replace it with outPipeFD read end
        dup2(outPipeFD[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(outPipeFD[0]); // not needed anymore

        // Close STDOUT and replace it with inPipe read end
        dup2(inPipeFD[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(inPipeFD[1]); // not needed anymore

        // execl() is cleaner than system() since it replaces the process
        // completely. Use /bin/sh instead if you'd like.
        execl("/bin/bash", "bash", nullptr);
        return 1; // to not run the parent code in case execl fails
    }
    // Parent

    // Close the read end of the write pipe
    close(outPipeFD[0]);

    // Close the write end of the read pipe
    close(inPipeFD[1]);

    sleep(1);
    int& out = outPipeFD[1]; // for convenience
    int& in = inPipeFD[0];   // for convenience

    // a list of commands, including an erroneous command(foobar) + exit
    for(std::string cmd : {"echo test", "var=worked", "echo $var", "foobar", "exit"}) 
    {
        std::cout << "EXECUTING COMMAND: " << cmd << '\n';
        auto [output, exit_status] = command(out, in, cmd);
        // print what was returned
        for(auto str : output) std::cout << str << '\n';
        std::cout << "(exit status=" << exit_status << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
EXECUTING COMMAND: echo test
test
(exit status=0)
EXECUTING COMMAND: var=worked
(exit status=0)
EXECUTING COMMAND: echo $var
worked
(exit status=0)
EXECUTING COMMAND: foobar
bash: line 7: foobar: command not found
(exit status=127)
EXECUTING COMMAND: exit

(exit status=257)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe this will solve our problem!
I do have one more issue that I would like to share with you, that is related to this. When running `system("/bin/bash -i")` and trying to export that new variable, I get these two errors: 
`bash: cannot set terminal process group (122365): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell`
Does this mean that I need to link the shell to some kind of system device to actually process the commands that are sent to it?

Comment: @D.Share Hmm, it seems your `bash` requires a real `tty` connected to the I/O so either one has to cheat and make up some code that pretends that it actually is a `tty` or the idea with `-I` was bad. I can come up with an alternative solution but I think I'll need to set the pipe in non-blocking mode. I'll work on that.

Comment: @D.Share I added an alternative. I tried to avoid making the pipes non-blocking, but found it hard to get it to handle all strange situations. Hope this one works for you.

Comment: Thank you @ted-lyngmo! The status reporting is really helpful and the delimiter generation and checking is genius. Outstanding work, thanks again.

Comment: @D.Share You're welcome! One word of caution though. If the user of the function starts background processes that also print to screen this will not work. In that case you could add a `wait` to the command list too perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, just to confirm, is that if a processed command starts its own child? Or if a processed command returns an exit status but continues to output to stdout?

Comment: @D.Share Both. If one uses`command(out, in, "program &");` it could possibly be saved by a `wait`, but in the case `command(out, in, "program_that_starts_subprocesses_that_outlives_parent");` it may not be possible. You'd need to scan not only the last thing `read` but look for the delimiter everywhere. The delimiter may also be interleaved with the output from the background program, destroying the possibility to find it. Tricky situation.